# Inno Setup syntax - OR, AND

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I must change a Inno Setup script. But I cannot compile it (every time I compile, I have to wait almost 1 hour for the build to finish). I need to know how to write the following expression that is in C++ pseudocode:

```c
if ((A==B) || (A==C))
{
  // do something
}
```

---

The question is how should I write that in Inno Setup script, and, if possible, do you know if this scripting language is specific for Inno Setup or can I find a guide somewhere? In the official website it's very hard to get what you want in a simple way, it's rather confusing and I couldn't find simple examples with `OR` (the examples are very very basic).

Comment: If you're looking for a guide, I suggest http://www.mirality.co.nz/inno/tips.php

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The language that is used by Inno Setup scripting engine is based on Pascal and at least the general syntax you can learn from Pascal language. Closest language to Inno Setup Pascal Script is Delphi (in which is Inno Setup written btw.). The code you've asked to translate would look like this:

```pascal
if (A = B) or (A = C) then
begin
  { do something }
end;
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this. By the way, is there a way to write comment other than {}? something to comment lines.

Comment: Yes, for the code section you may comment single line with `//` and comment block with `{ ...  }`